# Querying Active Directory with LDAP filter containing spaces

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am attempting to query ActiveDirectory via LDAP, but the query may contain spaces or other characters that may cause problems (hyphens?)

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(&(sn=Bloggs*)(givenName=Jo*))(displayName=Jo Bloggs))
```

It is an OR search e.g. in SQL it would be `WHERE (sn LIKE 'Bloggs%' AND givenName LIKE 'Jo%') OR displayName = 'Jo Bloggs'`

However, when I try the LDAP query, I get an error: `System.ArgumentException: The (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(&(sn=Bloggs*)(givenName=Jo*))(displayName=Jo Bloggs)) search filter is invalid`

Code for performing search:

```
string userName = "Jo Bloggs";
DirectoryEntry adroot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Environment.UserDomainName, "user", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(adroot);
search.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(&(sn={0}*)(givenName={1}*))(displayName={2}))", userName.Split(' ')[1], userName.Split(' ')[0], userName);
```

This is just a basic search, I would like to search other columns as well (Job Title, Telephone, Department etc), e.g. `WHERE title LIKE '%foo%' OR telephonenumber LIKE '%foo% OR department LIKE '%foo%'`

Also, could I cache the search, so ActiveDirectory doesn't get a lot of hits from people searching t for the same thing?

This also only finds one entry, I would like to search and display in a repeater all results that are found.

Comment: Accepted more of the answers to my previous questions now. However, there are a few that haven't answered to question (either there is no answer (e.g. can't be done, limitation of system), or the answers don't fully answer the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis. Try this working example:

```
string userName = "Jo Bloggs";
string baseQuery =
    "(&" +
        "(objectCategory=person)" +
        "(objectClass=user)" +
        "(|" +
            "(&" +
                "(sn={0}*)" +
                "(givenName={1}*)" +
            ")" +
            "(displayName={2})" +
        ")" +
    ")"; // <<< this is missing in your original query

userName = Regex.Replace(userName, @"[\(\)\*\\]", (match) =>
                {   // escape reserved chars
                    return "\\" + ((int)match.Value[0]).ToString("x");
                }, RegexOptions.Compiled);
string query = String.Format(query, userName.Split(' ')[1], 
                                    userName.Split(' ')[0], userName);
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(
    "LDAP://" + Environment.UserDomainName, "user", "password",
    AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher ds = 
       new DirectorySearcher(entry, query, null, SearchScope.Subtree))
    {
        SearchResultCollection res = ds.FindAll(); // all matches
        if (res != null)
            foreach (SearchResult r in res)
                Console.WriteLine(user.Properties["displayName"].Value);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** About escape sequences, you should refer to this document: [Creating a Query Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675768.aspx). I edit this answer to reflect that information.

> If any of the following special characters must appear in the query filter as literals, they must be replaced by the listed escape sequence.

```
  ASCII     Escape sequence 
character     substitute
    *           "\2a"
    (           "\28"
    )           "\29"
    \           "\5c"
   NUL          "\00"
```

> In addition, arbitrary binary data may be represented using the escape sequence syntax by encoding each byte of binary data with the backslash followed by two hexadecimal digits. For example, the four-byte value 0x00000004 is encoded as "\00\00\00\04" in a filter string.

Comment: Missing bracket was the reason for the code not working.. writing it in your way (breaking up into lines), makes it easier to understand and debug

Comment: What if displayName contains brackets, e.g. 'John Smith (PA to Director)' or department has & - 'Finance & Performance'?

Comment: fixed that, please take a look

Answer (score -1):

There is also another LINQ to AD http://adlinq.codeplex.com framework which implements more of the IQueryable extension methods (Single, First, Last, SingleOrDefault and many more) and has frequent updates.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use Linq to AD for searching - http://linqtoad.codeplex.com/